# In Python3/tkinter is there a way to temporarily stop accepting clicks in a Treeview widget?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

I have a GUI based in Python 3 and tkinter that has a big `ttk.Treeview`. I have defined methods for row selection (one click) and opening an advanced info panel (double-click). I need to ensure that, after being double-clicked, for the next one or two seconds, the Treeview state won't be changed by another click. Is it possible to deactivate Treeview mouse bindings, like what we do with buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a little more research, I was able to come up with a solution for this. I just created an empty method that is called when the tree widget is supposed to be inactive. So, we can use something like this to "unbind" all the mouse events and re-bind them a few seconds later, as needed:

```
def nothing(self, *event):
    """ # Hacking moment: A function that does nothing, for those times you need it...
    """
    pass


def bind_tree(self):
    """ # Bind mouse and keyboard events to their respective functions or methods...
    """
    self.tree.bind('<<TreeviewSelect>>', self.selectItem_popup)
    self.tree.bind('<Double-1>', self.show_details)
    self.tree.bind("<Button-2>", self.popupMenu)
    self.tree.bind("<Button-3>", self.popupMenu)

def unbind_tree(self):
    """ # Unbind all mouse and keyboard events, by binding them to an empty method...
    """
    self.tree.bind('<<TreeviewSelect>>', self.nothing)
    self.tree.bind('<Double-1>', self.nothing)
    self.tree.bind("<Button-2>", self.nothing)
    self.tree.bind("<Button-3>", self.nothing)
```

Then, in the rest of the code, We only need to call `bind_tree()` and `unbind_tree()` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```py
tree.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", my_select_function)
# Do some stuff
tree.unbind("<ButtonRelease-1>")
```